# How do I check the current state of a SwitchPreference?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-preferences, switchpreference

I have a `SwitchPreference` in my `SettingsFragment.kt` that changes the icon and title depending on if it's on or off.

This is the code for that:

```
notificationsPreference.onPreferenceChangeListener = Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener { _, newValue ->
    val switched = newValue as? Boolean ?: false
    if (switched) {
        notificationsPreference.icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this@SettingsFragment.requireContext(), R.drawable.ic_notifications_active)
        notificationsPreference.title = "Receive Notifications"
    } else {
        notificationsPreference.icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this@SettingsFragment.requireContext(), R.drawable.ic_notifications_off)
        notificationsPreference.title = "Mute Notifications"
    }
    true
}
```

This code works, however, let's say the user clicks the `SwitchPreference` to be off, leaves the `SettingsFragment` and comes back to it. It will show the `SwitchPreference` off, but the title and icon won't be correct. The correct icon and title would be the code I have in my `else` statement above.

How do I check the current state of a `SwitchPreference` before the user enters the `SettingsFragment`. I want to check it so that if the `SwitchPreference` is off, I can programmatically set the correct icon and title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SwitchPreference` maintains the current value in the `SharedPreference` using a boolean key/value pair.

So, you can do this whenever the `PreferenceFragment` shown using one of its lifecycle methods like `onCreatePreferences()`

```
override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle, rootKey: String) {
    setPreferencesFromResource(
        R.xml.settings,  // Your setting.xml file
        rootKey
    ) 
    
    val preference = findPreference(
        getString(R.string.my_preference_key) // Change this to the preference key set in the settings XML file
        val sharedPrefs =
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this@SettingsFragment.requireContext())

    // Get the preference value
    val isOn: Boolean = sharedPrefs.getBoolean(
        preference.getKey(),
        false // default value
    )
    
    if (isOn) {
        notificationsPreference.icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this@SettingsFragment.requireContext(), R.drawable.ic_notifications_active)
        notificationsPreference.title = "Receive Notifications"
    } else {
        notificationsPreference.icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this@SettingsFragment.requireContext(), R.drawable.ic_notifications_off)
        notificationsPreference.title = "Mute Notifications"
    }       
    
}
```

Make sure to change `R.xml.settings` to the your settings file name, and also the `R.string.my_preference_key` to the preference key.