# How to check the current state of a SwitchPreference?

Tags: android, kotlin, switch-statement, fragment, switchpreference

I have a `SwitchPreferenceCompat` and I want to say if Switch preference is enabled show Toast(switch preference is enabled) else it disables again shows a Toast(switch preference is disabled)
There were some questions like this but none of them worked for me.

Here is XML:

```
<PreferenceCategory app:title="عممومی">

    <Preference
        app:key="backUp"
        app:title="بشتیبان گیری آفلاین از اطلاعات" />
     

      <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        app:key="vibrate"
        app:defaultValue="true"
        app:summary="لرزش هنگام انتخاب یک آیتم"
        app:title="لرزش" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

And Setting Fragment:

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey)
    }
}
```

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68875154/14976321)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> myPref!!.onPreferenceClickListener =
>     Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener {
>         Toast.makeText(activity, "WORK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
>         true
>     }
> ```

You need to replace `onPreferenceClickListener` by `onPreferenceChangeListener`

```
override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {

    val myPref = findPreference<SwitchPreferenceCompat>("vibrate")

    myPref?.onPreferenceChangeListener =
       // The callback is triggered whenever the switch preference is changed
        Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener { pref, newValue ->

            if (pref is SwitchPreferenceCompat) {
                val value = newValue as Boolean
                if (value) Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "WORK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
                else Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            true
        }
}
```

Comment: I think you also need to change `val myPref = findPreference("backUp") as Preference?` to `vibrate` as the this is the key of your `SwitchPreferenceCompat`

Comment: backUp is a kind of button and that is completely different from switch